# BigQuery, Converting string into an ARRAY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table in BigQuery:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | [joe, becky, smith] |
| Second | [joe, matthew] |

Column B has type 'STRING'

I want to convert Column B into a big query array of ARRAY

I attempted to use `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY` but this does not work as the elements inside the arrays of B are not enclosed within double quotes (") (i.e. they are not of the form, `["joe", "becky", "smith"]`)

Answer (score 3):

Consider below

```
select a, 
  array(select trim(val) from unnest(split(trim(b, '[]'))) val) b
from `project.dataset.table`
```

when applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]